# Use flalign or alignat or align or similar environment to align to the left

Tags: align, horizontal-alignment

The following is a small example to use `flalign` environment to generate equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
The formula is:
\begin{flalign*}
  \lambdaup &= \lambdaup_1 + \lambdaup_2\\
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

The output aligns at the center:

```
The formula is
                  lambda = lambda_1 + lambda_2
```

How can I make the alignment to the left, using `flalign`, `alignat` or `align` environment? I mean:

```
The formula is
lambda = lambda_1 + lambda_2
```

According to Michael's comment, adding option `[fleqn]` to package `amsmath` and setting `\mathindent=0.0pt` will solve the problem. But this will make all equations align to the left. How can I make the function `locally` to some environment instead of the whole article?

Comment: Displayed equations are usually centered. You can pass the option `fleqn` to either the document class or to `amsmath` to get displayed equations that are aligned to the left. However, they are still indented slightly unless you change the value of `mathindent`.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, `mathindent` is a point.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use Flalign instead.

```
The formula is
\begin{flalign*}
a &= b+c &\\
  &= 1+1 &\\
  &= 2  &
\end{flalign*}
```

Comment: I just found that if the content in `flalign` has `math`, it doesn't work. Please have a look at the updated example.

Comment: You need to add `&` after each line, i.e. write `\lambdaup &= \lambdaup_1 + \lambdaup_2 &`.

Comment: @Michael: yes, adding `&` at the end of line does work. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelUmmels why we need to add `&` at the end?

Answer (score 23):

Using the `flalign` environment (numbered equations) or the `flalign*` (unnumbered equations) environment, left alignment can be obtained with two ampersands (`&`). If the only alignment you want is for the equations to be left-aligned, put an ampersand at the beginning and end of each line, like so:

```
\begin{flalign*}
  & \lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &\\
  & \Lambda = \Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2 &
\end{flalign*}
```

If you want to have left-alignment but also align by some character (say, the `=` sign), put the first ampersand immediately before the character you want to align by, and the second ampersand at the end of each line, like so:

```
\begin{flalign*}
  \lambda &= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &\\
          &= \Lambda &\\
          &= \Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2 &
\end{flalign*}
```

---

Credit to [Lauer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4374/lauer), whose [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14081/2271) I used to help me figure out the same issue, then expanded upon.

Comment: This, did it for me. I tried so many other solutions, but they did not work. The ampersands at the beginning and the end are crucial.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to give amsmath the parameter `fleqn`:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

Edit: This produces a slightly different output than `flalign*`.

Comment: @Michael: Now I know the option `fleqn`. Thank you. I think this option will work for all equations in article. This is its advantage and disadvantage since not all equations will be displayed to the left. So it is better to set right environment at where you want, just like what Lauer does.