# How to left align a set of equations

Tags: equations, align

I wanted to left align a set of equations. I've tried the solution provided in 
[aligning to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/use-flalign-or-alignat-or-align-or-similar-environment-to-align-to-the-left/).
It worked. But, I wanted to have a single equation number for the entire `flalign` in order to refer to it later. Like in case of `equation+split`. While using `equation+align`, I am able to get it. But, if I use `equation+flalign` the equations are still being centered. Is there a way to do it?

Example using `equation+align`,

```
\begin{equation}
     \begin{align}
      \mbox{Minimize } & x_1+x_2+x_3 \\
      \mbox{Subject to} & \\
       & x_1+x_2 \leq 10 \\
       & x_2+x_3 \leq 8 \\
       & x_1+x_3 \leq 5 
     \end{align}
\end{equation}
```

I would like to do this while the equations are left aligned. 
It will be even better if the equations can be spaced a little (for example, 1 cm) from the left margin instead 
of starting from the left margin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `align` into `aligned`.

Comment: Another hint: Since you're already using the `amsmath` package, you may want to use the package's command `\text` instead of the basic-LaTeX `\mbox`. In the present case, the outcome is the same. However, in more general math settings, `\mbox` may give you undesired results because it sets its argument always in `\textstyle`, whereas `\text` adapts the size of its output to the surrounding math mode (which could be `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One option will be to use

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

On the other hand, this option (`[fleqn]`) can be passed to `\documentclass` also as

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

The MWE will be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show frames
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
     \begin{aligned}
      \text{Minimize } & x_1+x_2+x_3  \\
      \text{Subject to} &\\
       & x_1+x_2 \leq 10 \\
       & x_2+x_3 \leq 8 \\
       & x_1+x_3 \leq 5 
     \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The output will be

[image]

But all the equations in the document will be left aligned by this approach.

The `equation` environment will put the equation in display mode by definition. To space only one equation left aligned, as you wish, one way is to use `\phantom` as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show frames
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
     \begin{aligned}
      \text{Minimize } & x_1+x_2+x_3   \\
      \text{Subject to} &\\
       & x_1+x_2 \leq 10 \\
       & x_2+x_3 \leq 8 \\
       & x_1+x_3 \leq 5 
     \end{aligned}
     \phantom{\hspace{6cm}} %%<---adjust the value as you want
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using flalign environment with an extra & at the end of the last equation line also will align the system of equations to the left.

Comment: There are cases when the `flalign` environment does not work (due to a certain package). In those cases, the above is a very neat solution.