# how to left-align equations

Tags: spacing, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to left align a set of equations.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54478/how-to-left-align-a-set-of-equations)

I want to write an equation in latex , 
the code is :

```
   \begin{align*}
  \log (\sigma_{t}(X)) =&\log( \prod_{x \in X} \frac{1}{1-xt}) \\
            &= \sum_{x \in X} log(\frac{1}{1 - xt}) \\
            &= - \sum_{x \in X} log(1 - xt) \\
            &= - \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(- xt)^{n}}{n} \\
            &= \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{x^{n}t^{n}}{n} \\
            &= \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{x \in X}  \frac{x^{n}}{n} t^{n} \\
            &= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{P_{n}(X)}{n} t^{n}
 \end{align*}
```

How to align left the equation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change the alignment of this equation, use `flalign*` in place of `align*`. If you want all equations to be left-justified try

`\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`.

See the [amsmath package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) for details.