# Left-align equations not working

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am trying to left-align some equations so they line up nicely.

I'm using align with `[fleqn]` per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28650/how-can-i-use-an-align-environment-flush-left) and `setlength` per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8740/problem-using-option-fleqn-in-amsmath-package). But it doesn't seem to have worked. I tried the `fleqn` environment too per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60835/how-to-left-align-equations) but it didn't do the trick either.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A\triangleright B\triangleright A & \iff & x'Ax\geq x'Bx\cap x'Bx\geq x'Ax\forall x\\
 & \iff & x'Ax=x'Bx\cap x'Bx=x'Ax\forall x\\
 & \iff & x'Ax=x'Bx\forall x\\
 & \iff & x'Ax-x'Bx=0\forall x\\
 & \iff & x'(A-B)x=0\forall x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please make your code compilable. As of now, it has no chance of doing so since you've embedded an `align` environment inside `\[...\]`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the welcome. Edited removing brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the following what you want? It's achieved by removing the second `&` alignment point from each row. (Note that whereas the deprecated `eqnarray` syntax requires two `&`s, `align` requires only one.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate the width of the text block
\begin{align*}
A\triangleright B\triangleright A 
 & \iff x'Ax\geq x'Bx\cap x'Bx\geq x'Ax\forall x\\
 & \iff x'Ax=x'Bx\cap x'Bx=x'Ax\forall x\\
 & \iff x'Ax=x'Bx\forall x\\
 & \iff x'Ax-x'Bx=0\forall x\\
 & \iff x'(A-B)x=0\forall x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, it was the difference between `eqnarray` and `align` that got me. Thanks!