# Align equation left

Tags: equations, align

Here is my split equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a_{ijk} =& \frac {Pr(M_{I} =2  \&  M_J=1 \& M_K =1 | I=i , J=j , K=k)}{Pr (M_I =1 \& M_J =1 \& M_K=1 | I=i , J=j)} \\
            =& \frac {\mu_{ijk211}}{\mu_{ijk111}}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I want to align this equation to the left. Is this possible in an `equation` environment?

Comment: A neat all-weather solution is to use `\phantom`, as described in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54499/8666. This works in all situations.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I would not use the equation environment; rather, I would use flalign as such:
**(notice the && at the end of each line)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent A \hfill Z
\begin{flalign}
a_{ijk} &= \frac {Pr(M_{I} =2  \&  M_J=1 \& M_K =1 | I=i , J=j , K=k)}{Pr (M_I =1 \& M_J =1 \& M_K=1 | I=i , J=j)}&&\\\nonumber
            &= \frac {\mu_{ijk211}}{\mu_{ijk111}}&&
\end{flalign}

\noindent A \hfill Z
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Another way to go is to set the `fleqn` option for the document class. However, this left-aligns *all* of your equations and hence should not be used when you want at least some equations to remain centered.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent A \hfill Z
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
a_{ijk} &= \frac {Pr(M_{I} =2  \&  M_J=1 \& M_K =1 | I=i , J=j , K=k)}{Pr (M_I =1 \& M_J =1 \& M_K=1 | I=i , J=j)}\\
            &= \frac {\mu_{ijk211}}{\mu_{ijk111}}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\noindent A \hfill Z
\end{document}
```

For this output:

[image: Output 2]

As suggested by karlkoeller, if you want to get rid of the space between the left margin and the equation (to get a result similar to the first case), you should add `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}`.
If you later want to indent it back to its default value, you can use the same command with a value of `15pt`, which is the amount of `pt` a paragraph indent shifts its text to the right.

Answer (score 80):

Note: This doesn't answer the question exactly. But still try this solution first as it is probably the simplest.

Use `align`, and put `&` at the beginning of every line. Use `\\` to separate multiple equations.

```
\begin{align*}
& a_{ijk} = 2 \\
&(because ||V_1-V_2|| = \max_{i \in [d]}|V^i_1 - V^i_2|)
\end{align*}
```

(This works if you want to left align a set of equations, but the whole equations could be at the center if your equations are short)

Comment: This helps a lot. You aren't able to `\usepackage` in MathJax but its really a struggle finding any information for workarounds for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 20):

Put `&` at the beginning of the line for left alignment and `\\` at the end of the line to break line. Enclose the equation between `\begin(split)` and `\end(split)`

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&T_{eff}=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i.t_i \\
&=h_1t_1+(1-h_1)h_2t_2+(1-h_1)(1-h_2)h_3t_3+...+ \\
&(1-h_1)(1-h_2)...(1-h_{n-1})h_nt_n
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: What if my equation already involves the split environment?

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, if one desires **all** equations in the document to be flushed left by default, one can also define in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

Then, proceed to use `equation` or `align` or similar environments.

Answer (score 7):

Note `flalign` requires at least *two* groups of alignment, whence a supplementary ampersand.
 I wanted to point another possibility with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` (which loads `amsmath`). This environment can take an optional argument to set the distance from the left margin the equation(s) start (default is 0 pt). It works somewhat like the `subequations` environment in the sense that all (groups of) equations inside the environment will start at the left margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a_{ijk} =& \frac {Pr(M_{I} =2 \& M_J=1 \& M_K =1 | I=i , J=j , K=k)}{Pr (M_I =1 \& M_J =1 \& M_K=1 | I=i , J=j)} \\
            =& \frac {\mu_{ijk211}}{\mu_{ijk111}}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a_{ijk} =& \frac {Pr(M_{I} =2 \& M_J=1 \& M_K =1 | I=i , J=j , K=k)}{Pr (M_I =1 \& M_J =1 \& M_K=1 | I=i , J=j)} \\
            =& \frac {\mu_{ijk211}}{\mu_{ijk111}}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This answer addresses some possible misconceptions.

Note that there are two ways to interpret the questions -- if you use the wrong solution, you'll probably find that nothing works.

Summary:

[image: Summary]

The two ways to interpret the questions are:

1. You may want to left-align the equations **relative to each other**, or
2. You may want to left-align the equations **relative to the page margin**.

The solutions are, respectively,

1. To left-align the equations **relative to the page margin**, use one of the following:

   - [`flalign` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145660/250119).

     **Note that** `flalign` does not stand for "flush left align", [it stands for "full length align"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665972/aligning-equation-to-the-left#comment1655976_665972)!
     If you read `texdoc amsldoc`, its actual purpose is to:

     [image]

     which means, in this question it's used as a hack, the `&&` at the end of each line is used to **add a right-column equation that is empty**, so the left equation get moved to the left margin.

     Actually, one `&` works as well, [and it suffices just to put a trailing `&` on the first line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14081/250119) (the number of columns is automatically counted).
   - [`fleqn` environment from `nccmath` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467619/250119).

     In this case, `fl` indeed stands for "flush left".

     [image: nccmath package documentation]
   - [`fleqn` option of the document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145660/250119). This is actually [not an option of the documentclass itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404776/250119), rather it's forwarded to `amsmath` package, see `texdoc amsldoc` for documentation.

     [image: output of fleqn option]

     It's important to set `\mathindent` **after** loading `amsmath` package.
2. To left-align the equations relative to each other, [put the `&` before each equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400434/250119).

   ```
   \begin{align*}
   &1+2 = 3 \\
   &4 = 5-2+1
   \end{align*}
   ```

   Again, this work mostly as a hack -- the `align` equation aligns the *first* column to the right and the *second* column to the left, so if the first column is empty, the whole equation are aligned to the left with respect to each other.
3. To do both, combine the changes.

   Another method is to use `gather` combined with `[fleqn]`:

   [image: gather with fleqn]

   Or, of course, `gather` combined with `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` package.

   ```
   \begin{fleqn}
   \begin{gather*}
   1+2 = 3 \\
   4 = 5-2+1
   \end{gather*}
   \end{fleqn}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`multline*` did the trick for me

```
\begin{multline*}
p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\ 
- 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multline*}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time, but let me mention another way.
You can use `\hspace{10em}` at the end of any line and within few try you can figure out what value (instead 10) works best.