# How to insert a horizontal line in align env with some text at the end of the line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, cline

I'd like to have some math induction showing as below.(In an align environment `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`) How can I have the "by addition" text at the end of the line? I tried with `\cline` but failed to do that.

```
x = 1   y = 2
-------------- by addtion
  x + y = 3                z = 3
--------------------------------- by addition
       x + y + z = 6
```

Here is what I've got so far. I also wanted the equations to be centered but I found it was hard to do.

```
\begin{align*}
x = 1 & y = 2 \\
\cline{1-2}
x + y = 3 & & z = 3 \\
\cline{1-3}
&x + y + z = 6& \\
\end{align*}
```

[image: latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 3):

I created `\byx{<eq1>}{<eq2>}{<via>}{<eq-sum>}`, which can be nested.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\newcommand\byx[4]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$~#1\qquad#2~$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{~by #3}%
  \Shortstack[c]{\copy0 \rule[2.3pt]{\wd0}{.5pt}\rlap{\copy2} $#4$}%
  \hspace{\wd2}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \byx{%
    \byx{x=1}{y=2}{addition}{x+y=3}
  }{z=3}{addition}{x+y+z=6}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: You can add `\setstackgap{S}{<gap>}` to set the vertical gap of the stack. Default gap for `\Shortstack` is `3pt`.  The value can span the positive/negative range.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? `\\` will add a line break.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
text...\\ \\
x = 1, y = 2
\\------------ by addition\\
x + y = 3

\end{document}
```

Output example:

[image: Add line break and horizontal line in equation/math]

Comment: It seems similar. But I am trying to have it in a math environment so that I don't need to align everything by myself.

Comment: Then you should be more specific in your question. Your MWE is too vague.

Comment: Thx. Just added.

Comment: But still, what are you trying to get. Left or right alignment? Please post what ever code you have so I understand what you're aiming for here. As far as I can tell my example gives you what you want (left alignment).

Comment: You might consider reading through this post: [Align equation left](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145657/align-equation-left)

Comment: Thx so much. I just updated my question.