# How do I find the meaning of latex documentclass options?

Tags: sourcecode, documentation, class-options, resources

I saw someone using the [final] option for the beamer documentclass and wanted to see what it did. So I searched the package documentation here on CTAN and also found the directory on my computer that has the beamer source (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer on my machine) and then searched the files recursively for the word "final" (using grep -R final ./*) with no interesting results.

So my question is: where can one find the meaning of arbitrary documentclass options?

I am really surprised that looking through the source itself didn't yield the answer, since at some point, the options have to be parsed, I assume...

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `[final]` option – only a `[draft]` option. Perhaps it is  an option for a package that beamer loads without option? Normally the options are described in the documentation (`texdoc beamer`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Options to `\documentclass` are *global* options. That means they can be options for the document class and/or the following packages.

Class `beamer` does not know about option `final`. But packages like `graphics` can pick the global option. In case of `graphics` the meaning of option `final` is the default behavior of the package and the opposite of option `draft` that does not include the images and prints boxes with the image file name instead.

Options are usually documented in the documentation of the class or package that defines them. Since `beamer` does not define option `final`, it cannot be found in its documentation. In case of package `graphics` (as example), options `final` and `draft` are described in section "4.1 Package options" of the [graphics user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf):

> **draft**: suppress all the `special' features. In particular graphics files are not included (but they are still read for size info) just
>   the filename is printed in a box of the correct size.
>
> **final**: The opposite of `draft`. Useful to over-ride a global `draft` option specified in the `\documentclass` command.

Further reading:

- Section "2.2 Class and package options" in the [LaTeX user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/usrguide.pdf).

Comment: This seems like exactly what I needed to know. In the example that I had seen, they used the graphicx package, which presumably has similar options.

Comment: Is it customary to accept an answer right away if it meets one's needs or wait a day or two for the rest of the community to have a chance? I feel like I have seen people do both...

Comment: @ZachBoyd Package `graphicx` is an extension to package `graphics`. Internally, it loads package `graphics` and passes options `final`, `draft` to it.