# Aligning equation on the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I need to align equations of the left.

I wrote the following according to this topic : [Align equation left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145657/align-equation-left)

```
\begin{flalign}
p(1-p)^2 (\alpha |001\rangle + \beta |110 \rangle).hc +p^2(1-p) (\alpha |110\rangle + \beta |001 \rangle).hc& \\ \rightarrow X_3 \left( p(1-p)^2 (\alpha |001\rangle + \beta |110 \rangle).hc +p^2(1-p) (\alpha |110\rangle + \beta |001 \rangle).hc \right) X_3& \\
= p(1-p)^2 (\alpha |000\rangle + \beta |111 \rangle).hc +p^2(1-p) (\alpha |111\rangle + \beta |000 \rangle).hc& 
\end{flalign}
```

But the render is not good, and I have numerotations on the right :

[image]

The render is not good because as you can see the first line is not left aligned.

I don't understand what I did wrong (because in the topic associated they basically just use flalign as I did...??)

Comment: Do you want to align on the left all equations, or only some?

Comment: @StarBuck I do noy understand your question. To me the equations you show are aligned on the left.

Comment: @Denis the first line starts more on the right than the second line. So the first line is not aligned on the left

Comment: @Bernard all of them but actually I would be interested to know how I can chose a given alignment for specific equations as well

Comment: You have to specify the alignment point with an ampersand. If you want to left align all equations, use the document class option `fleqn`.

Comment: @StarBuck Sorry. I tend to confuse my left and my right ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like that would suit you ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&a = k\\
&b = k = l\\
&c = k = l = h
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d = k = l = h = m
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be perfect if I just dont have 3 numerotations ( (1),(2),(3) ) for the same align

Comment: @StarBucK, You can put a `\nonumber` on the lines you want unnumbered. Another tip, the `subequations` package

Comment: @StarBucK See my edit. If you want no equation number at all for the `align` replace `equation` by `equation*`

Answer (score 0):

Will the following be good enough?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\begin{align}
        \nonumber
        &p(1-p)^2 (\alpha |001\rangle + \beta |110 \rangle).hc +p^2(1-p) (\alpha |110\rangle + \beta |001 \rangle).hc \\
        \nonumber
        &\rightarrow X_3 \left( p(1-p)^2 (\alpha |001\rangle + \beta |110 \rangle).hc +p^2(1-p) (\alpha |110\rangle + \beta |001 \rangle).hc \right) X_3 \\
        \nonumber
        &= p(1-p)^2 (\alpha |000\rangle + \beta |111 \rangle).hc +p^2(1-p) (\alpha |111\rangle + \beta |000 \rangle).hc
\end{align}
\end{document}
```