# Writing multiline equation inside algorithmic pseudocode environment

Tags: equations, alignment, cases, pseudocode

I have the following code which produces the algorithm in the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[h]
        \caption{Q-learning}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Require Set of good nodes $V^g$, $score(u) \; \forall u \in V^g, \mbox{ number of episodes } E, \mbox{ budget size } b$, $\epsilon$
            \Ensure Learned parameters $\Theta_Q$
            \State Initialise replay buffer $M = \emptyset$
            \For{Episode $e \leftarrow 1 \mbox{ to } E$}
                \State $S_t \leftarrow \emptyset,\; C_t \leftarrow V^g$
                \For{Step $t \leftarrow 1 \mbox{ to } b$}
                    \State 
                    \begin{equation}
                        v_t \leftarrow 
                        \begin{cases}
                            \mbox{A node chosen uniformly at random from } C_t & \mbox{w.p. } \epsilon \\
                            \argmax_{v \in C_t} Q(S_t, v) & \mbox{w.p. } 1-\epsilon
                        \end{cases}
                    \end{equation}
                \EndFor
            \EndFor
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: image for question]

I would like line 5 to be less centred in the middle of the page and more in-line with where it would be under the for loop if it was a normal piece of text. Can I do this using the equation/cases environment or do I need to create it some other way?

Sorry if I have any imports missing for the equation etc. as it may be in my preamble

Comment: This may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145657/align-equation-left

Comment: @AlanXiang the accepted answer recommends not using an algorithm environment, but I am writing pseudocode so I need the algorithm environment.

Comment: Why don' you use a   `\\ $\begin{cases} … \end{cases}$`?

Comment: @Bernard perfect, thanks! I was unaware that cases worked if you were using the `$` environment! please, write this as an answer and I can upvote and accept it :)

Comment: There's a problem, though: you won't have an equation number, as with `equation`. Do you need it?

Comment: No, no equation number is required in this instance, so this still works for me :)