# How do I disable the auto-centering of equations when using \[\]

Tags: spacing

so yeah, I'm trying to stop using $$ for equations, but the fact that `\[` automatically places equations in the center is a bit annoying, is there a command to disable that.

Comment: Look into `fleqn` and `flalign`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145657/align-equation-left/145660#145660

Comment: ? $$ centers too and it is actually one of its disadvantages that fleqn doesn't work, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/2388. What you are doing to change that?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `fl eqn` = flush left equations but `fl align` is full length align, so only accidentally leftish aligned.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, but left flush can still be achieved with the `&&` trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fleqn` option to `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm} % This controls the indent

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    Some text before the equation.
    \[
    x = y + z
    \]
    Some text after the equation.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using input such as

```
This is some text before an equation\\
$x+y=y+x$\\
and this text follows
```

because using `$$...$$` would center the equation anyway.

Such way of coding your typescript is wrong under many respects, even if you use something like

```
This is some text before an equation\\[1ex]
$x+y=y+x$\\[1ex]
and this text follows
```

to get vertical space around the math display.

***Never*** use `\\` to end lines in normal paragraphs. TeX ain't a word processor!

If you want equations to the left, it's possible using `\[...\]` or other `amsmath` display environments, but avoid printing display math flush with the left margin.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Bad display}

The following fact should be known to every mathematician \\[1ex]
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}$\\[1ex]
and was definitely a surprise when it was discovered.

\section{Good display}

The following fact should be known to every mathematician
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
and was definitely a surprise when it was discovered.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want the display to be flush left,

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Not so good display}

The following fact should be known to every mathematician
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
and was definitely a surprise when it was discovered.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why isn't it really good? Because left aligned displays are usually employed along with equation numbers on the left. Look at the following.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Unnumbered}

The following fact should be known to every mathematician
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
and was definitely a surprise when it was discovered.

\section{Numbered}

The following fact should be known to every mathematician
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation}
and was definitely a surprise when it was discovered.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you set `\mathindent` to zero you get suboptimal output.

[image]