# Simple alignment question

Tags: horizontal-alignment

So I want to align my 'equals' sign and inequality signs. So I have done,

```
   \begin{align}
   \Rightarrow d(\mathbf x',\mathbf 0) & \geq d(\mathbf x,\mathbf 0) - d(\mathbf x',\mathbf x) \\
   &=  \varepsilon + \delta - d(\mathbf x',\mathbf x)
   \end{align}
```

This works fine, it aligns the signs however it also centres the whole equation. I don't want it to be centred, I just want it to start from the left and move to the right as normal text should.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: related: [How to left align a set of equations.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54478/579).

Answer (score 3):

Using `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` will left align all equations. You can use `flalign` environment instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \Rightarrow d(\mathbf x',\mathbf 0)
  &\geq d(\mathbf x,\mathbf 0) - d(\mathbf x',\mathbf x)   && \\     %% note two && at the end
  &= \varepsilon + \delta - d(\mathbf x',\mathbf x)
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\newcommand*\Vector[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \Rightarrow
  d(\Vector{x}',\Vector{0})
  &\geq d(\Vector{x},\Vector{0}) - d(\Vector{x}',\Vector{x}) \\
  &=    \varepsilon + \delta - d(\Vector{x}',\Vector{x})
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The best answer is definitely [Harish Kumar's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168668/15874).

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional argument:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```