# How to write a perfect equation parameters description?

Tags: equations, lists

Equation's symbols or parameters description are shown below, however, the `=` and the details of parameter are not aligned.

[image]

I want to make a parameters list for a equation like this, in which symbols, `=` and detail information are aligned in terms of vertical position.

```
where
   ...
   P   =   notional permeability factor
   N   =   number of waves
   Sd  =   damage level
   ...
```

A `tabular` environment will produce more spacing before and after text. So how to make the `=` vertical aligned?

The codes is provided:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{H_s}{\Delta D_{n50} } = 1.0~ P^{0.13}~ \left(\frac{S_d}{N} \right)^{0.2} \xi_m^P~ \sqrt{\cot \alpha}
\end{equation}
where: 

$H_s$ = significant wave height, equal to the average of the highest 1/3 of the waves

$\Delta$  = relative buoyant density, equal to $\rho_r / \rho_w - 1$, where     $\rho_w$ is the water density

$D_{n50}$ = nominal  diameter defined in Equation (2)

$P$ = notional permeability factor

$S_d$ = damage level 

$N$ = number of waves

$\xi_m$ = breaker parameter based on mean wave period $T_m$

$\alpha$ = slope angle
```

Comment: There is a package for that: [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl). Actually two I know of: [`nomentbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomentbl). Or you could even try `glossaries`. It really depends on how much effort you are willing to invest (i.e. writing a book vs short paper).

Comment: I'd just use `align*` and `\text` for the stuff after the `=`

Comment: @daleif, but how to align `=` in a fixed vertical position

Comment: Not understood, don't you know `align`? `&=`

Comment: @Count Zero what is the advantage of using Glossaries?  I thought this is only use at the end of the book. Please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Define your own environment for this; here I realize it as a two column alignment; the first column is typeset in math mode, the second one in text mode; the `=` is added automatically, with the correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}
An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{conditions}
 P     &  notional permeability factor \\
 N     &  number of waves \\   
 S_{d} &  damage level
\end{conditions}

\end{document}
```

[image: enter image description]

If your conditions are overlong, then you can use a different environment, that I call `conditions*`, based on `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{conditions*}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
   \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
  {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}
An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{conditions*}
 P    &  notional permeability factor and something 
          longer that needs to be taken at the next line\\
N     &  number of waves \\
S_{d} &  damage level
\end{conditions*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Variant for variable symbols

If different symbols are needed instead of `=` in each line, here's how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}

\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
   \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\newenvironment{conditions*}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
   \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{}>{${}}c<{{}$}@{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
  {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}
An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{conditions}
 P     & =       &  notional permeability factor \\
 N     & \sim    &  number of waves \\
 S_{d} & \propto & damage level
\end{conditions}

An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{conditions*}
 P     & =       & notional permeability factor and something 
                   longer that needs to be taken at the next line\\
 N     & \sim    & number of waves \\
 S_{d} & \propto & damage level
\end{conditions*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to have no break after “where:”, here's a variant of the first solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {#1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\begin{document}
An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
\begin{conditions}
 P     &  notional permeability factor \\
 N     &  number of waves \\
 S_{d} &  damage level
\end{conditions}
Some text after the equation.

\end{document}
```

The `conditions` environment has an optional argument for changing the fixed `where:`; so, for instance, `\begin{conditions}[with:]` will use “with:”.

[image]

A different version that allows for longer descriptions that needs to be wrapped across lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,calc}

\newlength{\conditionwd}
\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {%
   #1\tabularx{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}[t]{
     >{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X@{}
   }%
  }
  {\endtabularx\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\begin{document}
An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
\begin{conditions}
 P     &  notional permeability factor with some more text
          so this ends up to break across lines blah blah
          blah blah\\
 N     &  number of waves \\
 S_{d} &  damage level
\end{conditions}
Some text after the equation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\noindent` is a little bit right aligned, when using `\indent` it has more spacing compared to the original `\indent` value.

Comment: I did it on purpose; if you want to have the same indentation, add `@{\hspace{\parindent}}` at the start of the argument to `tabular` (or `tabularx`): `\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{\parindent}>{$}l...}`

Comment: Besides, how to make the line spacing same as the text line spacing?

Comment: @KOF It *is* the same line spacing as in the text.

Comment: I forgot I have defined `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` for `Table` entries, so how to make it as default in this cae, 'cause I dont wanna change it.

Comment: @KOF Just add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}` to the definition of the environment; you can put it between `\par` and `\noindent`.

Comment: What is the proper symbol between the variable and the first character of the variable description? Is `=` the most used symbol for this?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I'd say so.

Comment: This is great. Thanks @egreg. I wonder, how could one mix operators in the definitions? I need some lines to use `\sim` awhile others `=` (see [this mixture model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#Introduction))

Comment: @user815423426 You need to add another column. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @egreg thank you for your solution, it's neat and user friendly. I was wondering if there is a way to have the `where:` on the same line as the first defined parameter and allow the width of the word define the indent for the tabular? Or maybe have the `where:` in a further column preceding the current tabular without it repeating on every line?

Comment: @Fiztban I added it.

Comment: @egreg thank you ever so much have a good day!

Comment: @egreg sorry to be a bother again, I tried to adapt your command to my situation (I am using `\doublespace` for my text) and I would like the parameters to be defined in `\singlespace` when I write it as follows the `where:` becomes unwantedly indented `\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]{\singlespace#1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{${}:{}$} l}}{\doublespace\end{tabular}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}`. I similarly tried to adapt `conditions*` to do the same but encountered errors of `overfull box`and an unwanted indent

Comment: @Fiztban Please, make a new question

Comment: my adaptation of the `conditions*` command was `\newenvironment{conditions*}[1][where:]{#1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{}>{${}}c<{{}$}@{} l}}{\end{tabular}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}`. Thank you in advance if you are able to indulge my lack of expertise with LaTeX commands.

Comment: @egreg I will do

Comment: @egreg please find the question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225569/writing-neat-equation-parameter-definitions-with-singlespace-vs-doublespace-te) thank you.

Comment: Hi, @egreg, if I have a definition longer than a line it goes beyond the margins of my page with the `conditions` environment. How can I change this?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Sure you can! See the edit. :)

Comment: @egreg, nice solution, but not compatible with `ltablex`

Answer (score 21):

As daleif suggested you could use the align* environment. You get the alignment just like in tables with '&'. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    H_s &= \text{significant wave height, equal to the average of the highest 1/3 of
    the waves}\\
    \Delta &= \text{relative buoyant density, equal to }\rho_r\text{ / }\rho_w - 
    1\text{, where }\rho_w\text{ is the water density}\\
    D_{n50} &= \text{nominal  diameter defined in Equation \eqref{eq:dn50g50}}\\
    P &= \text{notional permeability factor}\\
    S_d &= \text{damage level}\\
    N &= \text{number of waves}\\
    \xi_m &= \text{breaker parameter based on mean wave period }T_m\\
    \alpha &= \text{slope angle}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This should work for you. This is the output:
[image: Output]

If you don't want all equations to be aligned left, you can use the flalign* environment, 
like suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/use-flalign-or-alignat-or-align-or-similar-environment-to-align-to-the-left).

Comment: thanks Dave, the symbols should be `\flushleft` though

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use the `tabbing` environmnent:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{H_s}{\Delta D_{n50} } = 1.0~ P^{0.13}~ \left(  \frac{S_d}{N} \right)^{0.2}  \xi_m^P~ \sqrt{\cot \alpha}
\end{equation}
where: 
\begin{tabbing}
\phantom{$D_{n50}\ $}\= \kill
$H_s$\> = significant wave height, equal to the average of the highest 1/3 of the waves\\
$\Delta$\> = relative buoyant density, equal to $\rho_r / \rho_w - 1$, where     $\rho_w$ is the water density\\
$D_{n50}$\> = nominal  diameter defined in Equation \eqref{eq:dn50g50}\\
$P$\> = notional permeability factor\\
$S_d$\> = damage level\\
$N$\> = number of waves\\
$\xi_m$\> = breaker parameter based on mean wave period $T_m$\\
$\alpha$\> = slope angle\\
\end{tabbing}
```

The first line in the tabbing environment will set the spacing (i.e. tabstop). The `\kill` command suppresses the line it precedes, otherwise you would have an extra space between 'where:' and the first definition.

[image]

Alternatively, instead of `\phantom{$D_{n50}\ $}` (the longest item on your list), you can use a fixed width: `\hspace{3cm}`.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old post but all of the solutions require the equation and the explanations to be given separately. I prefer to have a single environment that combines the equation and the explanation of its variables.

The code below defines a new `formula` environment where you specify the formula as the first argument and give the explanation of the variables as a comma separated list in the body  of the environment. For example, the code,

```
\begin{formula}{P+N=S_{d}}
 P    : notional permeability factor,
 N    : number of waves,
 S_{d}: damage level
\end{formula}
```

produces

[image]

Inspired by egreg's nice answer, there are additional arguments. You can use an exclamation mark if you want a line break after the `where:` and you can change the `where:` into anything you like using the (second) optional argument. So

```
\begin{formula}![where the wonderful notation we are using is:]{P+N=S_{d}}
 P    : notional permeability factor,
 N    : number of waves,
 S_{d}: damage level
\end{formula}
```

produces:

[image]

Additionally, there is a `formula*` variant that works in exactly the same way except that it does not print an equation number. For example, to display the formula in the OP we could use:

```
\begin{formula*}!{
   \frac{H_s}{\Delta D_{n50} } = 1.0~ P^{0.13}~ \left(\frac{S_d}{N} \right)^{0.2}
                \xi_m^P~ \sqrt{\cot \alpha}
  }
  H_s: {significant wave height, equal to the average of the highest 1/3 of the waves},
  \Delta:  {relative buoyant density, equal to $\rho_r / \rho_w - 1$, where
             $\rho_w$ is the water density},
  D_{n50}: nominal  diameter defined in Equation (2),
  P: notional permeability factor,
  S_d: damage level,
  N: number of waves,
  \xi_m: breaker parameter based on mean wave period $T_m$,
  \alpha: slope angle,
\end{formula*}
```

produces:

[image]

Notice that it is necessary to enclose the variable explanations that contain commas inside braces.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

% add a single explanation line - #3 gobbles any extra garbage
\def\ExplainVariable#1:#2:#3!!!{$#1$ &$\;\;=$ #2 \\}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{formula}{ t! O{where:} m b }{%
 \begin{equation}#3\end{equation}
  #2 \IfBooleanT{#1}{\\[1ex]}
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\ExplainVariable##1::!!!}%
  \tabular[t]{r@{}l}\docsvlist{#4}\endtabular
}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{formula*}{ t! O{where:} m b }{%
 \begin{equation*}#3\end{equation*}
  #2 \IfBooleanT{#1}{\\[1ex]}
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\ExplainVariable##1::!!!}%
  \tabular[t]{r@{}l}\docsvlist{#4}\endtabular
}{}

\begin{document}

  \begin{formula}{P+N=S_{d}}
     P    : notional permeability factor,
     N    : number of waves,
     S_{d}: damage level
  \end{formula}

  \bigskip

  \begin{formula}![where the wonderful notation we are using is:]{P+N=S_{d}}
     P    : notional permeability factor,
     N    : number of waves,
     S_{d}: damage level
  \end{formula}

  \bigskip

  \begin{formula*}{
     \frac{H_s}{\Delta D_{n50} } = 1.0~ P^{0.13}~ \left(\frac{S_d}{N} \right)^{0.2}
                  \xi_m^P~ \sqrt{\cot \alpha}
    }
    H_s: {significant wave height, equal to the average of the highest 1/3 of the waves},
    \Delta:  {relative buoyant density, equal to $\rho_r / \rho_w - 1$, where
               $\rho_w$ is the water density},
    D_{n50}: nominal  diameter defined in Equation (2),
    P: notional permeability factor,
    S_d: damage level,
    N: number of waves,
    \xi_m: breaker parameter based on mean wave period $T_m$,
    \alpha: slope angle,
  \end{formula*}

\end{document}
```

The basic idea to parse the body of the `formula` environment using `\docsvlist` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

Comment: I very much liked your idea, but it doesnt work with KOMA classes, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367418/adding-chapter-in-koma-scrbook-generates-a-latex-error-do-undefined
I'd be happy if you find a solution for this :)

Answer (score 5):

When I've faced this problem, I wrote the package [`eqexpl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqexpl) (since 14 Nov 2018 it is available on CTAN).  With it you could add in preamble

```
\usepackage{eqexpl}
\eqexplSetIntro{where:} % set parenthesis in the left of the first item
\eqexplSetDelim{=} % set delimiter to "="
```

and then in document

```
\begin{eqexpl}
  \item{P} notional permeability factor
  \item{N} number of waves
  \item{$S_d$} damage level
\end{eqexpl}
```

With this in preamble

```
\usepackage{eqexpl}
\eqexplSetDelim{=}
```

and this in the document

```
\begin{eqexpl}[25mm]
  \item{$H_s$} significant wave height, equal to the average of the
    highest 1/3 of the waves
  \item{$\Delta$} relative buoyant density, equal to $\rho_r / \rho_w - 1$,
    where $\rho_w$ is the water density
  \item{$D_{n50}$} nominal diameter defined in Equation (2)
\end{eqexpl}
```

you'll get

[image: result]

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/konstantin-morenko/latex-equation-explanation) and [brief documentation](https://konstantin-morenko.github.io/latex-equation-explanation/)

Comment: The `eqexpl` package is already included in texlive 2016?

Comment: No. I've finished it just a month ago.

Comment: As of today (14/Nov/2018), the package is now available from `CTAN`

Comment: Here, the notations are aligned from the right side. How is it possible to start all notations from the left side (all notations are left-aligned) and all definitions are also left-aligned?

Comment: @Katatonia, set `\eqexplSetItemAlign{l}` in the beginning of the document like [this](https://github.com/konstantin-morenko/latex-equation-explanation/blob/16fea59d4303bc6d80c1d8ca01f98d9de6c00ea3/eqexpl.tex#L265). Briefly described in docs.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try fairly easy to use `alignat` environment:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{3}
      &A   &= &e^{\pi}  \\
      &AB  &= &\sqrt{x} \\
      &ABC &= & \text{An equation with three letters on the left!}
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: Note that the spaces around the `=` sign are much too small.

Comment: @HendrikVogt, You are right! I noticed and searched for the reason. Based on [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49016/22492) answer, `alignat` doesn't add space between the columns.

Comment: Just write `&{}={}&` instead af `&=&` each time to fix the spacing.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, where there are lots of text on the right, `tabular` with symbol separation would have been sufficient (and simpler):

```
\begin{tabular}{l @{ $=$ } l}
$P$ & notional permeability factor\\
$N$ & number of waves\\
$S_d$ & damage level \\
$f(x,y,z)$ & distribution
\end{tabular}
```

Resulting in

[image]

It should be possible to replace `@{ $=$ }` with `!{=}` since the `!` adds space before and after the separator but I can't get it work.

Ps: thanks to siteduzero.com

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as [@egreg's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95842/5049)?

Answer (score 2):

I created an Excel based solution to maintain symbols definitions, units and equations in an Excel worksheet. This Excel workbook generates LaTeX code to use in your document.

The Excel sheet automatically generates the right code for parameter definitions when you enter an equation.

This sheet can help you with a pleasant workflow in creating the parameter descriptions and saves manual work.

I chose a layout in which symbol units are also added. Here's an example:

[image]

I created a Github project to maintain this Excelsheet and accompanying .tex files and make it available to others: https://github.com/johanf85/Symbollist-maintain-Excel