# How to provide the explanations of a math equation?

Tags: equations

**How can I write the following equation with its explanation in latex ?**

---

[image]

Comment: Did you see [How to write a perfect equation parameters description](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95838/how-to-write-a-perfect-equation-parameters-description)?

Comment: We'll close the question as duplicate; this is not a judgment on your question, but only a way to keep the site as informative as possible. We're waiting for other contributions from you.