# Align multiline equation with expression after equal sign

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am trying to align a multiline equation using array within the equation but it turns out it doesn't do very well. The code I am using is as follows:

```
\begin{equation}    \begin{array}{lcl}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(d)\right\} &= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f_1(\delta).f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
& = exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
& = F_1 * F_2
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Can anyone suggest better way to deal with it ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`array` is not designed for aligning equations, it is designed for arrays and matrices. The `amsmath` package has a host of alignment environments, I give a couple of examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(d)\right\} &= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f_1(\delta).f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
& = \exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
& = F_1 * F_2
\end{align}

or

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(d)\right\} &= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f_1(\delta).f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
& = \exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
& = F_1 * F_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

note that `exp` is a multi-letter identifier so shouldn't be set in math italic.

Comment: @ David: That was very quick and works perfect. Thank you so much for your time and effort. I found this post and tried to follow that http://kogler.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/latex-multiline-equations-systems-and-matrices/

Comment: The second example works better in this case. If I use `\begin{align}` then it would put three equations on three lines. I just want only one.

Comment: @Jdbaba yes you can suppress two of the three numbers in aligned (`\notag`) sometimes things are clearly one long equation that you need to wrap, for chained `=` you can think of it as lots of equations or one long  one, anyway it's your document you can get to choose (there are other choices such as gathered and split as well...)

Comment: The following equation do not align using `aligned`. Is there any reason ? `\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F_1 \star F_2 = \int_0^t e^{m(t-\tau)} \frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} e^{\frac{-l^2}{4t}} \& = \frac{l e^{mt}}{2\pi^{1/2}}\int_0^t \frac{e^{(-(m\tau+l^2/{4t}))}}{\tau ^{3/2}} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}`

Comment: don't you want a `&` before the first `=` ?

Comment: Oh I totally missed that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

David's solution is the correct way to go for this case, but you *can* use `array` for this and sometimes it does come in handy:

[image]

So, the changes required are:

- Your second column should have been `l`eft aligned, not `r`ight aligned.
- You need to eliminate the inter column spacing using `@{}`, and use `&{}=` to get the proper math spacing around the equal signs.
- You should use `\exp` instead of `exp` as that is an operator and not a variable.
- Perhaps use `\cdot` instead of `.` (unless the lower dot notation is something I am not familiar with).

---

As David Carlisle commented, this formulas are displayed in the cramped `\textstyle`. If you desire the `\displaystyle` you need to add `\displaystyle` where it is needed (in this case the second line) to obtain:

[image]

Or, if you include the `array` pacakge then you can include the `>{\displaystyle}` style to the column specification (as illustrated in last part of MWE).

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}\noindent
Without \verb|\displaystyle|:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l@{}l}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(d)\right\} 
    &{}= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f_1(\delta) \cdot f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
    &{}= \exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
    &{}= F_1 * F_2
\end{array}
\end{equation}
With \verb|\displaystyle|:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l@{}l}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(d)\right\} 
    &{}= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f_1(\delta) \cdot f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
    &{}= \displaystyle\exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
    &{}= F_1 * F_2
\end{array}
\end{equation}
With \verb|\displaystyle| and \verb|array| package:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l@{}>{\displaystyle}l}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(d)\right\} 
    &{}= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f_1(\delta) \cdot f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
    &{}= \exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
    &{}= F_1 * F_2
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

You can eliminate the need for using `&{}=` by burying that in the `array` column spec:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l@{{}={}}l}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f(d)\right\} 
    & \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{f_1(\delta).f_2(\delta)\right\} \\
    & \exp(mt) \star \left\{\frac{l}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}} \exp(-l^2/{4t})\right\} \\
    & F_1 * F_2
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this will set the equation in `\textstyle` not `\displaystyle`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Wow, can't believe I have never noticed that yet. I got me some checking to do in my docs. :-)

Comment: You can use `array` package and `>{\displaystyle}l...`

Answer (score 3):

I always need to line up equals signs outside of a math environment, the best thing I found was to use center and tabular. This was best for lining up my equals signs in proofs, and in variable descriptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \approx h \left[ \dfrac{f(a)}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{\eta} f(x_i) + 
\dfrac{f(b)}{2}\right]
\end{equation}

where

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{ccl}\
$a, b$ & = & bounds of integration (endpoints of interval) \\
$f(x)$ & = & function \\
$h$ & = & step size \\
$\eta$ & = & number of trapezoids
\end{tabular}\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The empty lines before and after the word "where" are wrong. Apart from that, this does not really answer the question. Your answer has more to do with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95838/82917.