# How to add explanation of terms in equation

Tags: equations

[image]
How can I add explanation like that in figure in LateX under my equation?

Comment: I think http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95838/15925 should help.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" environment
\begin{document}
\[ \text{(main equation here)} \]
\begin{align*}
\text{where:}\quad 
K &= \text{conveyance for subdivision}\\
n &= \text{Manning's roughness coefficient for subdivision}\\
A &= \text{flow area for subdivision}\\
R &= \text{hydraulic radius for subdivision (area\slash wetted perimeter)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the text to the right of the `=` symbols can be quite lengthy, you may get line overflows. If that's the case, you could use `\parbox[t]{5cm}{...}` instead of `\text{...}` instructions, where `5cm` is a stand-in of the width of the text boxes you want. I recommend setting the material in narrow-width text boxes `\RaggedRight` rather than fully justified (which is the default); the latter can generate large interword gaps if the text box is narrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "align*" environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for "\RaggedRight" macro
\begin{document}
\[ \text{(main equation here)} \]
\begin{align*}
\text{where:}\quad 
K &= \text{conveyance for subdivision}\\
n &= \parbox[t]{5cm}{\RaggedRight Manning's roughness coefficient for subdivision}\\
A &= \text{flow area for subdivision}\\
R &= \parbox[t]{5cm}{\RaggedRight hydraulic radius for subdivision (area\slash wetted perimeter)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: since these are coded as separate displays, the vertical spacing between them will be rather wide.  might want to try `gather*` instead.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I thought about that too. However, given that there's no information at all about the structure and/or complexitiy of the "main" equation, and given further that the question is only about how to typeset the equation's "explanatory stuff", I decided to go with a very simple `\[...\]` construct for the MWE. Maybe the OP will furnish more information about the main equation...