# Writing neat equation parameter definitions with \singlespacing vs \doublespacing text

Tags: formatting, equations, lists, koma-script

This question is based off the answer for the [How to write a perfect equation parameters description?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95838/how-to-write-a-perfect-equation-parameters-description/95842?noredirect=1#comment530227_95842) question:

I would like to have the parameters defined using `\singlespacing` as I am currently using `\doublespacing` for my thesis spacing. Both the suggested `conditions` and `conditions*` environments have proven of great use and I have also attempted to adapt the `conditions*` to reflect the `no break after where:` variant which I wish to implement.

Defining `\singlespacing` as I have done causes the `conditions` to have an unwanted indent and a `missing \endgroup inserted` error though visually it works

Defining the `conditions*` as I have done by adapting the above-mentioned variant also causes an unwanted indent and I cannot work out how to insert the `\singlespacing` parameter without causing errors.

Here is my MWE with all my modifications made:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespace

\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {\singlespace#1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{${}:{}$} l}}
  {\doublespace\end{tabular}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}


\newenvironment{conditions*}[1][where:]
  {#1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{}>{${}}c<{{}$}@{} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\begin{document}

An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
\begin{conditions}
 P     &  notional permeability factor \\
 N     &  number of waves \\
 S_{d} &  damage level
\end{conditions}
Some text after the equation.

Another equation with symbols
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}

\begin{conditions*}
 P     & :       &  notional permeability factor \\
 N     & \sim    &  number of waves \\
 S_{d} & \propto & damage level
\end{conditions*}
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking for typographical beauty in a double spaced document is a lost in advance battle.

You can limit the damages with something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \vspace*{-.5\belowdisplayskip}%
   \linespread{1}\selectfont #1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{${}:{}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{minipage}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\newenvironment{conditions*}[1][where:]
  {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \vspace*{-.5\belowdisplayskip}%
   \linespread{1}\selectfont #1 \begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$} @{}>{${}}c<{{}$}@{} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{minipage}\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

An equation just to start
An equation just to start
An equation just to start
An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
\begin{conditions}
 P     &  notional permeability factor \\
 N     &  number of waves \\
 S_{d} &  damage level
\end{conditions}
Some text after the equation.
Some text after the equation.
Some text after the equation.
Some text after the equation.
Some text after the equation.
Some text after the equation.
Some text after the equation.

Another equation with symbols
Another equation with symbols
Another equation with symbols
Another equation with symbols
Another equation with symbols
Another equation with symbols
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
\begin{conditions*}
 P     & :       &  notional permeability factor \\
 N     & \sim    &  number of waves \\
 S_{d} & \propto & damage level
\end{conditions*}
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.
and so this is where we continue with some more text after the equation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the correct command is `\doublespacing`, not `\doublespace`.

Comment: Again thank you for all your help, I am still rather confused about spacing pro's and cons and how to go about them, I am required to used a ~1.5 line spacing for my text so a friend set me up to use `\doublespacing` with the `setspace` package explaining that the `\linespread{1.5}` command was more trouble than its worth. I am still none the wiser. Thank you for all.

Comment: Hi again, I have been using your code and it's been suiting me wonderfully. However I cannot seem to affect the font used within the environment which is currently in sans-serif for the last column. I am using `kpfonts` and my text is in Roman `\fontfamily{jkp}` how do I allow the second column in `conditions` and third column in `conditions*` to be in roman `jkp` font?

Comment: @Fiztban Please, make a new question with the failing code.