# Equation Parameters alignment

Tags: equations, lists, margins

This question is similar to many others (infact the code I am using comes from an answer in a previous question: [How to write a perfect equation parameters description?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95838/how-to-write-a-perfect-equation-parameters-description))

The comment section is becoming really long and I just think it would be easier to start a different thread (apologies for the inconvenience)

My current code reads:

```
\usepackage{array,tabularx,calc}

\newlength{\conditionwd}
\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {%
   #1\tabularx{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}[t]{
     >{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X@{}
   }%
  }
  {\endtabularx\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\begin{document}
\citet{hernandez1992probabilistic} further refines the PROLAM model and uses a virtual work calculation (see equation \ref{eqn:PROLAM deflection} to calculate the deflection ($\Delta$) which can be used in standard elastic deflection MOE calculations \ref{eqn:MOE4pt}.

\begin{equation}
    \Delta = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[\left(\frac{M_x m_x}{E_c I_i}+\frac{kV_xv_x}{A_iG_i}\right) \times \Delta_x \right]
    \label{eqn:PROLAM deflection}
\end{equation}

\begin{conditions}
    $\Delta$        & The total glulam beam deflection at $x$,\\
    $M_x$           & The bending moment at $x$ caused by actual loading,\\
    $m_x$           & The bending moment at $x$ caused by a unit load at the midspan of the beam,\\
    $V_x$           & The shear at $x$ caused by actual loading,\\
    $v_x$           & The shear at $x$ caused by a unit load at the midspan of the beam,\\
    $k$             & A form factor (1.2 for rectangular section),\\
    $E_c$           & A constant MOE value used in the transformed cross section,\\
    $I_i$           & The moment of inertia of the ith transformed cross section at x,\\
    $A_i$           & The transformed area at the ith transformed cross section at x,\\
    $G_i$           & The shear modulus of the ith transformed cross section at x,\\
    $\Delta_x$      & The increment at which calculations are performed,\\
    $n$             & The total number of increments along the beam length.\\
\end{conditions}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

As you can see, the parameter descriptions produces an overfull box. Does anybody know why this is? Could it possibly be to do with one of my other `\packages`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should *not* leave a blank line between `\end{equation}` and `\begin{conditions}` or the description might be detached from the equation.

Nor you should have a blank line before `\begin{equation}` under any circumstance.

On the other hand, such a long description of variables is quite likely to produce bad page breaks, be it detached or not from the equation.

Probably a simple list environment is better for such cases: the equals signs are not necessary and can be replaced by the verb *is*.

Here's a fixed version of your code; I've made several small fixes and you can compare them with your version. After `=` there is no capital letter: they're heavy and don't go along with the commas; `ith` should be `$i$th` and `at x` should *always* be `at $x$` (even better, `at~$x$`). Ending with `\endtabularx\\[\baselineskip]` will produce a warning.

```latex
\usepackage{array,tabularx,calc}

\newlength{\conditionwd}
\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {%
   #1\tabularx{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}[t]{
     >{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X@{}
   }%
  }
  {\endtabularx\\[\belowdisplayskip]}

\begin{document}
\citet{hernandez1992probabilistic} further refines the PROLAM model and uses a virtual work calculation (see equation \ref{eqn:PROLAM deflection} to calculate the deflection ($\Delta$) which can be used in standard elastic deflection MOE calculations \ref{eqn:MOE4pt}.

\begin{equation}
    \Delta = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[\left(\frac{M_x m_x}{E_c I_i}+\frac{kV_xv_x}{A_iG_i}\right) \times \Delta_x \right]
    \label{eqn:PROLAM deflection}
\end{equation}

\begin{conditions}
    $\Delta$        & The total glulam beam deflection at $x$,\\
    $M_x$           & The bending moment at $x$ caused by actual loading,\\
    $m_x$           & The bending moment at $x$ caused by a unit load at the midspan of the beam,\\
    $V_x$           & The shear at $x$ caused by actual loading,\\
    $v_x$           & The shear at $x$ caused by a unit load at the midspan of the beam,\\
    $k$             & A form factor (1.2 for rectangular section),\\
    $E_c$           & A constant MOE value used in the transformed cross section,\\
    $I_i$           & The moment of inertia of the ith transformed cross section at x,\\
    $A_i$           & The transformed area at the ith transformed cross section at x,\\
    $G_i$           & The shear modulus of the ith transformed cross section at x,\\
    $\Delta_x$      & The increment at which calculations are performed,\\
    $n$             & The total number of increments along the beam length.\\
\end{conditions}

\end{document}
```

[image: something]

Here's with a list.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,calc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\conditionwd}
\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {%
   #1\tabularx{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}[t]{
     >{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X@{}%>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}
   }%
  }
  {\endtabularx\par\addvspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}
\citet{hernandez1992probabilistic} further refines the PROLAM model and uses 
a virtual work calculation (see equation~\ref{eqn:PROLAM deflection}) to calculate 
the deflection ($\Delta$) which can be used in standard elastic deflection MOE 
calculations~\ref{eqn:MOE4pt}
\begin{equation}
    \Delta = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[
      \left(\frac{M_x m_x}{E_c I_i}+\frac{kV_xv_x}{A_iG_i}\right) \times \Delta_x
    \right]
    \label{eqn:PROLAM deflection}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{itemize}[labelindent=0pt,leftmargin=*,widest=$M_x$,align=left,itemsep=0pt]
\item[$\Delta$]   is the total glulam beam deflection at $x$,
\item[$M_x$]      is the bending moment at $x$ caused by actual loading,
\item[$m_x$]      is the bending moment at $x$ caused by a unit load at the midspan of the beam,
\item[$V_x$]      is the shear at $x$ caused by actual loading,
\item[$v_x$]      is the shear at $x$ caused by a unit load at the midspan of the beam,
\item[$k$]        is a form factor ($1.2$ for rectangular section),
\item[$E_c$]      is a constant MOE value used in the transformed cross section,
\item[$I_i$]      is the moment of inertia of the $i$th transformed cross section at $x$,
\item[$A_i$]      is the transformed area at the $i$th transformed cross section at $x$,
\item[$G_i$]      is the shear modulus of the $i$th transformed cross section at $x$,
\item[$\Delta_x$] is the increment at which calculations are performed,
\item[$n$]        is the total number of increments along the beam length.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your second suggestion of setting out, thanks. Is there a way I could get the first and last line of the `\begin{itemize}` to be automatically generated and then just change the `widest=$M_x$` value?. Maybe a new command or macro type of thing? Still kind of new to this.

Comment: Or perhaps when I type `\begin{equation}` it produces something like this: https://imgur.com/ooLgCdB . If you could just point me to a similar question somewhere else that would be perfect.

Comment: @AaronRhodes What's the problem if a dumb *editor* underlines keywords?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean?

Comment: @AaronRhodes The picture shows the editor's window. Those red underlines have no consequence on TeX, or do they?

Comment: They have no influnece, my Tex editor recognizes normal words instead of command inputs.

Comment: I have written a new question about the automatic generating of the code here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545702/how-to-automatically-generate-code?noredirect=1#comment1378476_545702

Answer (score 3):

There is an indent on the line where the `conditions` environment begins. In your example, the `conditions` environment is defined as

```
\newenvironment{conditions}[1][where:]
  {%
   #1\tabularx{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}[t]{
     >{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X@{}
   }%
  }
  {\endtabularx\\[\belowdisplayskip]}
```

So when the `conditions` environment is called with the default value `where:` for its optional argument, "where:" is written, and a `tabularx` environment begins. The width of this `tabularx` is defined to be `\textwidth` minus the width of "where:". Hence, the indent at the beginning of the line is not taken into account in the width of the `tabularx`: as you can see on your on your picture, the extra width on the parameters description matches the length of an indent. So just adding `\noindent` right before the `conditions` environment will solve the spacing issue.

Also, the `tabularx` environment called by `conditions` already places the first column in math mode, so you should not place manually the content of every cell between `$`.