# Undefined control sequence in equation caption

Tags: errors, captions, undefined

```
  \begin{equation}

 \centering \Large \textbf{$\lambda_{c} = \frac{18.64}{B \times E^{2} }$ }

 \label{eq1:Critical wavelength}
 \end{equation}
\begin{center}
\captionof
{equation}{where B is the bending magnet magnetic  field ( B = 1T ) , E is the energy of the booster}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `\captionof` is not a standard command and is presumably the command that tex reported is undefined, although you did not show the error message, also `\Large` will have generated a warning as size commands are invalid in math mode, `\centering` also does nothing useful inside `equation`

Comment: What David says, but also blank lines are not allowed inside `equation`.

Comment: I made edits but the error still appears :(

Comment: you can not have blank lines in equation, `\textbf{$...$}` does nothing at all and it is _very_ unusual to use captions with equations, the text `where...` would normally just be set as normal text after the equation.  You have not provided a usable test document nor said what output you want, only provides a fragment  that is really hard to guess what you want it to do.

Comment: Related: [How to write a perfect equation parameters description?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95838/5764)

Comment: Also you should have made a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a test document from your fragment

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}

 \centering \Large \textbf{$\lambda_{c} = \frac{18.64}{B \times E^{2} }$ }

 \label{eq1:Critical wavelength}
 \end{equation}
\begin{center}
\captionof
{equation}{where B is the bending magnet magnetic  field ( B = 1T ) , E is the energy of the booster}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 
    
?
```

as blank lines are not allowed in math mode.

Deleting the blank lines you get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Large invalid in math mode on input line 6.
```

so deletimg `\Large`

you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \captionof
```

as `\captionof` is defined by the `caption` or `capt-of` packages, but adding

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
```

defines `\captionof` command but as equations captioning is not set up you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> \@writefile{\ext@equation 
                                  }{\protect \contentsline {equation}{\prote...
l.14 \end{document}
                   
?
```

as the equation already has an equation number it is hard to guess what formatting you would want for a separately numbered caption, so I suggest deleting this. Also `\centering`  and `\textbf` are doing nothing in this context, so I think you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{equation}
 \lambda_{c} = \frac{18.64}{B \times E^{2} }
 \label{eq1:Critical wavelength}
 \end{equation}
where $B$ is the bending magnet magnetic  field ($B = 1T$),
$E$ is the energy of the booster.


\end{document}
```