# flalign doesn't work in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, equations, horizontal-alignment, align

I want to write just one equation from left in a beamer documentclass, but it seems that `\begin{flalign}` doesn't work, and everything that I write will be centered. I **don't** want to use `\usepackage[fleqn]{beamer}` as it will make all the equations to start from left. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{flalign}
&\min\hspace{0.5cm}\sigma_{ASE}^2x^{-1}+\zeta_1x^2+\zeta_2z &&\\
&\text{s.t.}\hspace{0.5cm}&\mathds{1}^Tp=1 &&\\
& p\geq 0 &&\\
& a^Tp\leq P_t &&\\
& a^T p=x &&\\
& b^T p=z &&
\end{flalign}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and this is my output:

There is a similar post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/use-flalign-or-alignat-or-align-or-similar-environment-to-align-to-the-left), but it does not give me any solution. Any help?

Comment: note that `fl` in the `fleqn` option stands for flush left but the `fl` in `flalign` stands for full length, it isn't designed to be flush left so much as take up the full width of the page so starting at the left edge...

Comment: so is there anyway to handle it? I am trying to put that part here to run it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I editted my post now

Comment: `$\displaystyle 5+6=11$` on a line by itself.

Comment: @egreg what about the new code?

Comment: @CLAUDE What's the purpose of `flalign`? I see none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all the ams alignments it isn't really designed for single line equations (and isn't designed to make flush left at all) but....

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{flalign*}
&5+6=11&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{flalign*}
\min\hspace{0.5cm}&\sigma_{ASE}^2x^{-1}+\zeta_1x^2+\zeta_2z &\\
\text{s.t.}\hspace{0.5cm}&\mathds{1}^Tp=1&\\
& p\geq 0 &\\
& a^Tp\leq P_t &\\
& a^T p=x &\\
& b^T p=z &
\end{flalign*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But for the original problem (which you can see it in the problem), I get centered output again :(

Comment: @CLAUDE added the expression you had originally, looks left aligned to me?

Comment: It worked finally, I really appreciate your help David

Comment: can you explain how this works? What are you doing?

Comment: @robertspierre I did nothing special at all, it's just demonstrating standard usage of `flalign`