# Aligning mathematical equations throughout paper

Tags: equations, formatting, align, matrices

I am wondering how I can get vertical alignment of the equations spread out over multiple align-environments:

```
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{y}_{t} &= \mathbf{A'} \cdot \mathbf{x}_{t} + \mathbf{H'} \cdot \boldsymbol{\xi}_{t} + \textbf{v}_{t},\\
    \boldsymbol{\xi}_{t} &= \mathbf{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{\xi}_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t},
\end{align*}

Here, $\mathbf{y}_{t}$ is a vector of observed contemporaneous variables; $\mathbf{x}_{t}$ is a vector of observed exogenous and lagged exogenous variables, and  $\boldsymbol{\xi}_{t}$ is the vector of unobserved states. The vectors of stochastic disturbances are assumed to be Gaussian and mutually uncorrelated, with mean zero and covariance matrices $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, respectively:

\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{v}_{t} & \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{R})\\
    \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t} & \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{Q})
\end{align*}

The first-stage model is represented by the following matrices:

\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{y}_{t} &=   \begin{bmatrix}
                        y_{t} & \pi_{t}
                        \end{bmatrix}\\
    \mathbf{x}_{t} &=   \begin{bmatrix}
                        y_{t-1} & y_{t-2} & \pi_{t-1} \pi_{t-2,4}
                        \end{bmatrix}\\
    \boldsymbol{\xi}_{t} &=     \begin{bmatrix}
                                y^{*}_{t} & y^{*}_{t-1} & y^{*}_{t-2}
                                \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
```

To clarify, the equations, from a vertical point of view, the equations do not start at the same point in the page: they are centered on the page according to their length.
I would like all equations to have the same starting point on the page, such that they 'vertically align'.

Furthermore, how does one impose a matrix transpose in the `bmatrix` environment?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't really want to align *all* equations throughout a paper, do you?

Comment: @Bernard just per section would be great.

Comment: Also, please only ask one question per post. What do you mean by "matrix transpose in the `bmatrix` environment" ?

Comment: If you know the widest left and right side expressions, you can make all the equations think they are the same width by using \phantom, \mathrlap and \mathllap (mathtools).  Or \settowidth and \makebox.

Comment: Off-topic: In the expression for `\mathbf{x}_t`, is an `&` symbol missing between `\pi_{t-1}` and `\pi_{t-2,4}`?

Comment: @mico you are right, I adjusted it

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a single `align` environment and the `\intertext` command for the text between groups of alignments, but it's designed for short sentences, so, in case a `\intertext` happens at the bottom of a page, it may go to the next page, leaving an  unwanted blank space at the bottom of the page.

I don't think this is a good idea – one aligns only equations which are tightly linked: what would be the meaning of aligning, say, the formula for the discriminant of a quadratic equation and a trigonometric identity? Equations are not a marching troop.

Anyway, for what it's worth, here is a code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{y}_{t} &= \mathbf{A'}\mathbf{x}_{t} + \mathbf{H'}\boldsymbol{\xi}_{t} + \textbf{v}_{t},\\
    \boldsymbol{\xi}_{t} &= \mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{\xi}_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t},
\intertext{Here, $\mathbf{y}_{t}$ is a vector of observed contemporaneous variables; $\mathbf{x}_{t}$ is a vector of observed exogenous and lagged exogenous variables, and $\boldsymbol{\xi}_{t}$ is the vector of unobserved states. The vectors of stochastic disturbances are assumed to be Gaussian and mutually uncorrelated, with mean zero and covariance matrices $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, respectively:}
    \mathbf{v}_{t} & \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{R})\\
    \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t} & \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{Q})
\intertext{The first-stage model is represented by the following matrices:}
    \mathbf{y}_{t} &= \begin{bmatrix}
                        y_{t} & \pi_{t}
                        \end{bmatrix}\\
    \mathbf{x}_{t} &= \begin{bmatrix}
                        y_{t-1} & y_{t-2} & \pi_{t-1} \pi_{t-2,4}
                        \end{bmatrix}\\
    \boldsymbol{\xi}_{t} &= \begin{bmatrix}
                                y^{*}_{t} & y^{*}_{t-1} & y^{*}_{t-2}
                                \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aside: I would also recommend dropping the `\cdot` directives -- they're neither required nor particularly helpful.

Comment: @Mico:  I didn't focus on this aspect of the problem, but you're right. I've changed the code.

Comment: @Bernard this is great! thanks. But you suggest that I watch out with using \intertext close to the end of the page?

Comment: Unless you're OK with possibly large blank spaces at the bottom of pages…

Comment: @Bernard It appears that my file does not respond to \intertext, I do have the mathtools package though

Comment: ??? Anyway, `\intertext` is defined in `amsmath`; `mathtools` adds only `\shortintertext` (with a tighter spacing).  Didn't you forget \\ before `\shortintertext`?

Comment: Also `bm` should be used; load it after `mathtools` so it will redefine `\boldsymbol` to be the same as `\bm` (which is however simpler to type).

Answer (score 1):

If you want every  `equation` environment to be left aligned, you can add the option `fleqn` when loading the `amsmath` package

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

or use `flalign` or `flalign*` environments instead if you only want this locally.

PLease see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/use-flalign-or-alignat-or-align-or-similar-environment-to-align-to-the-left) for more information.

**EDIT using barbara beeton advice**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter \@mathmargin=10pt\makeatother % to set flalign margin to 10 pt
\begin{flalign}
1+2=3
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took a look, but I would prefer the equations still to be centered and vertically aligned within a section. fleqn aligns everything to the left. Thanks!

Comment: if the `fleqn` option is set, it should be possible to set the left margin for math with the following: `\makeatletter \@mathmargin=<amount of indent> \makeatother`.  this muxt be done *after* `\begin{document}`.  (not tested.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just tested your solution and it works ! Big thanks for the advice